# Doctrine's generates invalid alter SQL sentence when trying to update schema

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

When I'm trying to run a schema:update I get the following error.

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException] An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE Messages CHANGE Title Title VARCHAR(55) etc...
```

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

The MySQL is 5.5.25, and as a matter of fact it's not accepting any sql trying to CHANGE xxx yyyy, but it's working nice when the sql is trying to CHANGE COLUMN xxx yyy.

So, I don't understand why doctrine 2 is generating alter sql sentences that are missing the word COLUMN. Is there anything I'm missing ?

Thanks so much for drop some light into this Doctrine/Symfony black-box...

Comment: I "solved" this by creating the db again: console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql  

and schema:update works again reflecting any change on the entity.orm.yml mapping

Comment: The `COLUMN` keyword is shown as optional in the docs.  Unfortunately, you didn't post the complete error message or the complete query, so it's tricky to guess, at this point, what actually went wrong.